# How to remove "created by" on SharePoint blog post item?

Tags: web-part, column, blog, layouts

I recently created a blog site and posted few blog posts but then I realized that "created by" column is showing on the item.

I tried to check what page layout a post is using but I simple found nothing. I then realised that a post appears as some form of a web part, so I quickly opened the web part properties thinking that perhpas this use content query but realized there is nothing much you can do about the web part properties.

I run 1000 searches on the net and I found nothing.

If anyone knows how to remove this column, please I would really appreciate your help on this one.

Comment: Why is it a bad thing that users see who drafted the blog post?

Comment: Lets just say I have a P.A who posts blogs on my behalf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog post rendered by xslt transformation. In this case you should change XSL template for your posts in `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL` folder. You can use [this post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/customize-sharepoint-2010-blog-post/) as start point to understand how does it work.

Comment: Please, keep in mind that changes in `14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\XSL` folder are **not supported** by Microsoft. For example, these files could be rewritten during applying Cumulative Update or Service Pack.

Comment: It's true, in the post that I provided the XSL file is copied and renaimed. Then the path to this file are set in web part through SPD. Also you should keep in mind that if you cahnge blog.xsl this changes will be applyed to all sites. it is not a good approach.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same requirement for a company Blog where several authors are posting articles but the visitors should not see the author name.

The simple approach is to use the following CSS, e.g. add it to your masterpage, to hide the author:

```
.ms-rightblogpost div.ms-PostFooter span.ms-postfootercolor:first-child,
.ms-rightblogpost div.ms-PostFooter nobr
{
    display: none;
}
.ms-rightblogpost div.ms-PostFooter span.ms-postfootercolor
{
    margin-left: -6px;
}
```

That worked for me, but if you want to remove it server-side a more advanced solution would be to create a copy of the file blog.xsl (located at 14\template\layouts\xsl) and point the Blog WebPart to your custom customblog.xsl and modify that file.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might help others if they are still looking for an answer.

1. If you are in SharePoint 2013, add a script editor to the page where all the blog posts are shown (blog site landing page).
2. Then insert the below snippet in the script editor web part, between the style tags.

```
<style>
    .ms-blog-postList > li > .ms-blog-postBox > .ms-blog-postBoxMargin > .ms-metadata, .ms-textsmall{
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

This should hide the text that says "by ...." below the title of the blog post.