# Hide "created by and date" in blog

Tags: blog, branding

I found this post

[How to remove "created by" on SharePoint blog post item?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26754/how-to-remove-created-by-on-sharepoint-blog-post-item)

It tells you how to remove the created by, it rocks! But I am still trying to figure out how to hide the "created on" (or published, whatever) date as well.

Anyone able to help please?

Comment: I see two solutions in your link, which method did you use to hide the `Created By` portion?  If you went with css, you should be able to use IE dev tools to locate the `Created On`, and hide it as well.

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint 2013  `PublishedDate` property is rendered as a div element:

```
<div class="ms-metadata">Saturday, May 24, 2014</div>
```

The same way is rendered `Author` property.

CSS solution how to hide  `PublishedDate` and `Author` properties in Blog view:

```
div.ms-metadata {
   display: none;
}
```